# Conditional Validation using jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using jquery-validate 1.11.0

In my form, i have a condition that if text is input in field A, fields B & C become required. If text is input in field B, A & C become required and so on and so forth. Also, if any text is in Field D, clear it out.

If text is input in Field D, then clear fields A, B, C and make them not required.

I have a bug where If I fill out field A first, it seems to submit bypassing the other 2 fields as required. If i fill out field b or c first, it ensures that field A is required.

http://jsfiddle.net/rockitdev/mxtXX/47/

```
<form id="search" name="search" method="post" action="">
    <label for="a">Text A</label>
    <input id="a" type="text" class="search-person" />
    <label for="b">Text B</label>
    <input id="b" type="text" class="search-person" />
    <label for="c">Text C</label>
    <input id="c" type="text" class="search-person" />
    <label for="d">Text D</label>
    <input id="d" type="text" class="search-hcn" />
    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>

$('.search-person').focus(function () {
    $('.search-hcn').val(' ').removeClass("required");
    $('.search-person').addClass("required");
});

$('.search-hcn').focus(function () {

    $('.search-person').val(' ').removeClass("required");
    $('.search-hcn').addClass("required");
});

$('#search').validate();
```

Comment: so use required validation for all fields.Then it solves the problem

Comment: not all fields are required necessarily...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `name` attributes on the `input` fields solves the problem.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxtXX/52/)

```
<form id="search" name="search" method="post" action="">
    <label for="a">Text A</label>
    <input id="a" type="text" class="search-person" name="person1" />
    <label for="b">Text B</label>
    <input id="b" type="text" class="search-person" name="person2" />
    <label for="c">Text C</label>
    <input id="c" type="text" class="search-person" name="person3" />
    <label for="d">Text D</label>
    <input id="d" type="text" class="search-hcn" name="hcn" />
    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

---

The `debug` option is useful for finding such errors.

```
$('#search').validate({debug: true});
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the jQuery Validate plugin requires that the `name` attribute always be present on all input elements.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `depends` option provided by validate plugin to do this.

Note: Removing the value is not a part of the validation

```
$('#search').validate({
    rules: {
        a: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $('#b').val().length > 0 || $('#c').val().length > 0
                }
            }
        },
        b: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $('#a').val().length > 0 || $('#c').val().length > 0
                }
            }
        },
        c: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $('#a').val().length > 0 || $('#b').val().length > 0
                }
            }
        },
        d: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $('#a').val().length == 0 || $('#b').val().length == 0 && $('#c').val().length == 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UkMA9/1/)